# Total number of Isotropic Vectors in Finite Field

Tags: finite-fields, quadratic-forms

How can I find the total number of isotropic vectors in $\mathbb{F}_{q}$?

I searched about Lidl and Nederreiter formula but that is not clear to me.

Comment: First you need to specify a bilinear form.

Comment: I'm also not entirely clear as to what the field-vector space pair is (and yes, need the bilinear form too.)

Comment: The book "Introduction to Finite Fields and their Applications" by the authors of this formula (besides, could the OP say what is this formula precisely ?) can be uploaded on a site that can be reached with the key words "boise state lidl and niederreiter"